# linear regression lines cannot show on time series plot in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series, xts

I am new in plotting time series. I downloaded a time series data and calculated a linear equation and I would like to add it in the time series plot. I want to show the year in the plot so I used index(stk) as x-axis input.

code:

```
library(quantmod)

stk <- suppressWarnings(getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE,
                                   src = "yahoo", periodicity = "daily"))
stk <- na.omit(stk)

stk.lm1 <- lm(log(Cl(stk)) ~ c(1:nrow(stk)), data = stk)
plot(index(stk), log(Cl(stk)), type = "l", lwd = 3, las = 1)
abline(coefficients(stk.lm1)[1], coefficients(stk.lm1)[2], col="blue")
```

I know it is the plot using index(stk), how can I do to keep the x axis of plot in date and can I use plot.xts or other like ggplot2 to do the same things? Please advise, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't dificult to do the plot that you want in base r plot or ggplot2 here is what you what:

```
plot(index(stk), log(Cl(stk)), type="l", lwd=3, las=1)
lines(x = index(stk.lm1$fitted.values), y = stk.lm1$fitted.values,col = "blue")
```

for the base r plot I added a line with the fitted values of the linear regression that I extracted with the `$` signed and the dates of theme. Take into account that `lm` respect the structure of the data so the results are `xts`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stk, aes(x = index(stk), y = as.numeric(log(Cl(stk)))))+geom_line(lwd=1)+
  geom_line(aes(x = index(stk.lm1$fitted.values), y = stk.lm1$fitted.values),col = "blue")+
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Log Price")
```

For ggplot2 is quite similar. First you have to initiate the plot with `ggplot` where you defined the data and aesthetics (`aes`), then you add a line with `geom_line` and for the extra line I used the this command and define the new line in a new `aes` the same way I did it with the base r function.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it still did not show up in the plot lines(x = index(stk.lm1$coefficients[1]), y = stk.lm1$coefficients[2],col = "blue")

Comment: my lm is use c(1:nrow(stk)) and my plot is use index(stk), therefore my line can't show up in the plot, do my guess correct ? thanks

Comment: ggplot2 also show Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Comment: @Peter Chung  you don't have to use your coefficients for the line, use the fitted values of your linear regression that's what I use and it works. Take a look at my answer and see that I don't use the coefficient anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ggplot solution. You shouldn't have to calculate the linear regression coefficients yourself:

```
# convert stk to data frame & specify your x-axis variable explicitly
stk.df <- as.data.frame(stk)
stk.df$Date <- as.Date(rownames(stk.df))

# plot
ggplot(stk.df,
       aes(x = Date, y = log(AAPL.Close))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +             
  labs(x = "Year", y = "log(AAPL's closing value)") +
  theme_bw()
```

The `geom_smooth` line takes care of the regression. Set `se = TRUE` if you want to include a confidence interval around the line.

[image: plot]